# Great Expectations: How to add a partition (column partition) in an Athena External Table in a checkpoint reference in GE?

Tags: python, data-quality, great-expectations

The setup is GE v3 and I am using AWS Athena as a Data Source. However, I couldn't find a way to tell the "expectation" that the table in actually partitioned with a relative path in S3 like 's3://path_to_bucket/path_to_db/path_to_table/version=2022-02-01'.

I am looking for a way to run a `expect_column_values_to_be_unique` but when it takes the next parition 's3://path_to_bucket/path_to_db/path_to_table/version=2022-02-02', it returns a fail.

However, it only happens because it takes both  'version=2022-02-02' and 'version=2022-02-01' to verify the uniqueness on the table's primary key.

My question is: how can I pass version as an argument to the expectation / checkpoint?

Comment: Can you plz share your datasources yaml file configuration?